# jQuery Mobile changePage show transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to transition into a new page with jQuery Mobile, but everytime I do it, the new page will show on top of the old page and just overshadow the old page. I know it's supposed to cover, but I know I'm not suppose to be able to see the two pages at once.

This is my javascript code

```
<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $("#page2 *").swipeleft(function(event) {
        $.mobile.changePage("page3.html", {
            transition : "slideup"
        });
    });

    $("#page2 *").swiperight(function(event) {
        $.mobile.changePage("page1.html", {
            transition : "slideup"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: For the new page, is the body's background set to `transparent`?

Comment: No, the new page shows transparent when I do this code. I don't want it to do that.